# What can I use the ExpressCard slot on my laptop for, with regards to upgrading?

Tags: upgrade, dell-inspiron, expresscard

I don't know much about the ExpressCard slot, but I do gather from the wikipedia page it could be used to easily upgrade some features of my laptop.

I'm running a Dell Inspiron 1520, with absolutely no modifications. If possible, though unlikely, I'd like a faster processor, more RAM, or a better graphics card.

Is any of that possible with just the ExpressCard slot? I'd rather not have to crack open the case to make modifications.

If so, where can I buy these parts and which ones should I buy?

If not, what the heck is this slot for then?

Comment: Taken out of context, the last line of this question is extremely hilarious, just thought I'd point that out

Answer (score 0):

Out of that list, you may find a few graphics cards - although, I haven't heard of anything for a while and they were pretty expensive.

The expresscard should be thought of as a PCI Express slot... The number one usage is to add more ports to your system.... Network, Esata etc.

In addition, you can actually get converters that will give you a PCI Express slot - [See here](http://www.magma.com/pciexpress.asp), but again, they can be pretty expensive.

Comment: What sorts of graphics cards can work with this?

Comment: Expresscard graphics cards! They are their own (specialised) category!

Comment: Where can I find some of those?

Comment: google external gpu expresscard. Thunderbolt is a better interface for this though.